# How to Avoid Blending with Background When Enabling Blending

Tags: three.js, shader, point-clouds

I'm trying to implement what potree does to implement the blended splats. In the [this example](http://potree.org/demo/potree_1.3/showcase/lion_head_simone_garagnani.html), when disabling `EDL` and switch the `quality` option to `Splats` in the `Appearance` folder, it shows the blending effects.

My question is that how it can avoid those points blended with the background. When I enable blending in my own project, the points get blended with my background color and look not good. What's the elegant solution to avoid blending with the background?

EDIT:

You can see the points are getting blended with the white background. I'm using a custom shader to set the alpha value. In this image, the alpha value is 0.5.

[image]

Comment: Can you give a picture example of what you're seeing in your project? Also, are you using standard materials for your points, or do you have a custom shader?

Comment: So you want them to blend with each other, but not with the background?

Comment: @TheJim01 Yes. I don't want the points get blended with the background.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I use the `NormalBlending` in three.js. Changing the background alpha value doesn't make any sense. The final color is only related to the source alpha value but not the destination alpha value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potree uses a more complex blending function that requires 3 passes.

1. Visibility Pass: Renders the depth.
2. Attribute Pass: Does additive blending, but only for points with that are at most *blendDepth* units behind the depth buffer.
3. Shading/Normalization Pass: Normalizes the additive output to go from a bright additive to the smoothly blended look.

[image]
(edit: taken from http://www.ahornung.net/files/pub/Hornung_PBG05.pdf)

The attribute pass outputs a weighted sum of attribute values into the rgb channel, and a sum of weight into the alpha channel. 
The weight w for each points depends on the distance to the center. 
The output of the fragment shader is: `gl_FragColor = vec4(w * rgb, w)`

[image]

The normalization pass is a screen space post processing shader that divides each color in the framebuffer by the weight:
`gl_FragColor = vec4(weightedSumOfRGBs / sumOfWeights, 1.0)`

The final result are smoothely blended points with a transition hardness that depends on the weight function:

[image]

Check this thesis for a more detailed explanation (chapter 4.2.2):

https://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/research/publications/2016/SCHUETZ-2016-POT/SCHUETZ-2016-POT-thesis.pdf

Or this original paper of the algorithm:

http://www.ahornung.net/files/pub/Hornung_PBG05.pdf

Edit:

Also, to avoid seeing through to the backgroud, clear the buffer with a black color and alpha = 0, then render your points with the high quality 3-pass splatting algorithm and in the last step, render the background. The background will only be visible in areas where no points were rendered.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an answer to the question, but it is certainly a good description, even if it is a plagiarism.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I tried to give an answer to the question on how it's done in potree, not a scientific puplication with proper citations. Besides, I've also linked to the sources of the images. I've never seen someone expect an "Image taken from.." in a stackoverflow answer. Plagiarism is certainly not what I had in mind, or self-plagiarism in case of image 2 and 3.

Comment: @Markus How do I store the sumOfWeights? In the color buffer, I can only store value from 0.0-1.0.

Comment: @K.Miao You have to render to a floating point texture, which is not bound to a range of 0 to 1. This may help: https://github.com/potree/potree/blob/master/src/viewer/viewer.js#L2300

and this is where the render target for the attribute pass is initialized: https://github.com/potree/potree/blob/master/src/viewer/viewer.js#L2321

The EDLRenderer also does something slightly different to avoid seeing through to the background. The attribute pass renders into a different framebuffer and the EDL pass reads from that fbo and renders the shaded result to the main fbo, over the background.